# code for searching from file using GUI

Tags: java, swing

---

I'm looking for a code that allows me to search from file , for example, in my program which is shoes shop's program . I should design and implement interfaces which have to search data from file TXT. the idea is that when I choose one item like type of shoes the program should display all other times such as color, size and price .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is obviously a homework question. 

I presume that your class already taught you how to read data from a text file. Perhaps you could make you question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_frm/thread/b46a36a74174a80/3495f1d41e7e4c26) of a program that does [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) in a `JTable`. The program's array  of sample data could easily be read from a file.